# How can I set the google ChartRangeFilter to hour?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

The example for ChartRangeFilter is showing only years, I would like to set it up to hours, for example: starting from midnight to 23:59:59 pm.

range :

00:00:00

01:00:00

02:00:00

03:00:00

04:00:00

...

23:00:00

here is the example code on jsfiddle from Alex https://jsfiddle.net/alex4uthis/ZmVcZ/128/

code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['controls', 'charteditor']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('date', 'X');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Y1');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Y2');

    data.addRow([new Date(2014,  0, 1), 1,123]);
    data.addRow([new Date(2014,  1, 1), 6,42 ]);
    data.addRow([new Date(2014,  2, 1), 4,49 ]);
    data.addRow([new Date(2014,  3, 1), 23,486 ]);
    data.addRow([new Date(2014,  4, 1), 89,476 ]);
    data.addRow([new Date(2014,  5, 1), 46,444 ]);
    data.addRow([new Date(2014,  6, 1), 178,442 ]);
    data.addRow([new Date(2014,  7, 1), 12,274 ]);
    data.addRow([new Date(2014,  8, 1), 123,4934 ]);
    data.addRow([new Date(2014,  9, 1), 144,4145 ]);
    data.addRow([new Date(2014, 10, 1), 135,946 ]);
    data.addRow([new Date(2014, 11, 1), 178,747 ]);
    
    data.addRow([new Date(2015,  0, 1), 31,1253]);
    data.addRow([new Date(2015,  1, 1), 24,4532 ]);
    data.addRow([new Date(2015,  2, 1), 234,349 ]);
    data.addRow([new Date(2015,  3, 1), 2009,3486 ]);
    data.addRow([new Date(2015,  4, 1), 589,4756 ]);
    data.addRow([new Date(2015,  5, 1), 946,4744 ]);
    data.addRow([new Date(2015,  6, 1), 878,4542 ]);
    data.addRow([new Date(2015,  7, 1), 1562,9874 ]);
    data.addRow([new Date(2015,  8, 1), 4123,934 ]);
    data.addRow([new Date(2015,  9, 1), 7144,145 ]);
    data.addRow([new Date(2015, 10, 1), 8135,46 ]);
    data.addRow([new Date(2015, 11, 1), 9178,47 ]);

    var control = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        controlType: 'ChartRangeFilter',
        containerId: 'control_div',
        options: {
            filterColumnIndex: 0,
            ui: {
                chartOptions: {
                    height: 50,
                    width: 600,
                    chartArea: {
                        width: '80%'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

    var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        chartType: 'LineChart',
        containerId: 'chart_div',
        options: {
          width: 620,
          chartArea: {
            width: '80%'
          },
          hAxis: {
            format: 'MMM',
            slantedText: false,
            maxAlternation: 1
          }
        }
    });

    function setOptions() {
        var firstDate;
        var lastDate;
        var v = control.getState();

        if (v.range) {
          document.getElementById('dbgchart').innerHTML = v.range.start + ' to ' + v.range.end;
          firstDate = new Date(v.range.start.getTime() + 1);
          lastDate = new Date(v.range.end.getTime() - 1);
          data.setValue(v.range.start.getMonth(), 0, firstDate);
          data.setValue(v.range.end.getMonth(), 0, lastDate);
        } else {
          firstDate = data.getValue(0, 0);
          lastDate = data.getValue(data.getNumberOfRows() - 1, 0);
        }

        var ticks = [];
        for (var i = firstDate.getMonth(); i <= lastDate.getMonth(); i++) {
          ticks.push(data.getValue(i, 0));
        }

        chart.setOption('hAxis.ticks', ticks);
        chart.setOption('hAxis.viewWindow.min', firstDate);
        chart.setOption('hAxis.viewWindow.max', lastDate);
        if (dash) {
          chart.draw();
        }
    }

    setOptions();
    google.visualization.events.addListener(control, 'statechange', setOptions);

    var dash = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard'));
    dash.bind([control], [chart]);
    dash.draw(data);
    }
</script>
<div id="dashboard">
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
    <div id="control_div"></div>
<p><span id='dbgchart'></span></p>
</div>
```

How to set the range to show only hours?, please help

Comment: will you please clarify? the data for the chart spans more than one day, we can show hours on the filter, but they will be repeated to fill the date range...

Comment: can you check here pls https://jsfiddle.net/alex4uthis/ZmVcZ/128/

Comment: I reviewed the fiddle earlier. you can add the following to the filter's `chartOptions`, but it will simply repeat the same hour(s) since the data spans more than 1 day --> `hAxis: {format: 'hh'},` -- so I don't really understand what you're trying to accomplish.